# Ui-sref doesn't work when I click on them

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I have a html file

```
<div class="list">

  <a  ui-sref="sideMenu.settings.profileSettings" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-email"></i></a>
    User Profile
  </a>
   <a ui-sref="sideMenu.settings.profileSettings" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    Vehicle
  </a>
</div>
```

and a js file

```
.state('sideMenu.settings.profileSettings', {
        url: "/profileSettings",
        templateUrl: "templates/Settings/profileSettings.html",
        controller: 'profileSettingsController'

    })
```

Now whenever I click on the state. It updates the url. It means it's executing but it doesn't update the view. I have beem scratching my head but can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qo1G2e79T6BpyjWtxOHS?p=preview). *Not fully sure what is not working, because there are now really many resources and Q & A here revealing the mystery of the UI-Router... but ok*

I used your states like this:

```
  .state('sideMenu', {
      url: "",
      template: '<div ui-view></div>',
  })
  .state('sideMenu.settings', {
      url: "",
      template: '<div ui-view></div>',
  })
  .state('sideMenu.settings.profileSettings', {
    url: "/profileSettings",
    templateUrl: "templates/Settings/profileSettings.html",
    controller: 'profileSettingsController'
  })
  .state('sideMenu.settings.vehicle', {
    url: "/vehicle",
    templateUrl: "tpl.html",
  })
```

*As we can see, I just showed the parents and added one another state vehicle.*

And with the index.html like that:

```
<div class="list">

  <a  ui-sref="sideMenu.settings.profileSettings" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    User Profile
  </a><br />
   <a ui-sref="sideMenu.settings.vehicle" class="item item-icon-left">
    <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
    Vehicle
  </a>

</div>
```

plus the target somewhere

```
<div ui-view=""></div> // here will be the parent state injected
```

It is working. Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qo1G2e79T6BpyjWtxOHS?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for posting the plunker!